# In angular 2+ (Component => Service A => ServiceB), need help to understand the flow

Tags: angular6

In angular 2+,  I have a component A which calls service A where i make some changes and call service B (Http Calls) and get the data which is simply passed back to service A, now i need to subscribe into service A to see the data and also subscribe into Component A to display data there?

why i need to subscribe at 2 places which means its making the http calls twice (which is not good at all)

what is the best way where I can fetch and store data in Service A by subscribing and do all manipulation and simply send that object back to component A to display it? even I try to make a variable in subscribing section in service A but when I try to log that variable outside the subscribe block. it is undefined.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

while searching for the answer, I found one way (or can called worked around) that is to use "async-await" feature in angular with HttpClient.

which will basically wait at the same line of execution till you get result (success or error). and then proceed further with next line of execution.

for example:
 `async myFunction() {
    this.myResult = await this.httpClient.get(this.url).toPromise();
    console.log('No issues, it will wait till myResult is populated.');
  }`

Explanation:

adding async in front of the function to let it know that execution need to wait and the desire place (mostly at http service call as I need to wait till I get the result) we put await. so execution will go under wait period till it get the response back. and later. simply return the variable.